# Debian TUI to GUI

Tags: debian

I have a console-only version of Debian (latest one). Is there any way to upgrade to the GUI without having to reinstall the whole system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look [here](https://wiki.debian.org/DesktopEnvironment?action=show&redirect=CategoryDesktopEnvironment) for  instructions on installing most of the major `GUIs` available on `Debian`.

**GNOME**

```
apt-get install aptitude tasksel
tasksel install gnome-desktop --new-install
```

**KDE**

```
apt-get install aptitude tasksel
aptitude install ~t^desktop$ ~t^kde-desktop$
```

**XFCE**

```
apt-get install xfce4
```

**LXDE**

```
apt-get install lxde-core
apt-get install lxde
apt-get install task-lxde-desktop
```